# Call a PHP function from a JavaScript Ajax caller

Tags: php, jquery

I need to make an ajax call to my php function inside my php class.

The folders are like this:

```
controllers (folder)
-----User.php (php file)
View (folder)
-----js (folder)
---------myjavascriptfile.js
```

inside that `myjavascriptfile.js`
i have this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../controllers/User.php/newUser",
            data: { name: "John" }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
```

#### The error

i get error that the newUser is not exist, though this is my `User.php`

```
<?php

class User {
    function newUser($name){
        return "asdf";
    }
}
```

sorry if this is a silly question, i am not that good in php without frameworks :)

Comment: Do you have a route pointing to that method?

Comment: @Rangad no i don't have . should I ?

Comment: Well, how do you expect php to know what method to call on what url? It could be the case that I don't get your application layout. But as I understand it, you just have class with a method. Nothing will be executed when you access that file.

Comment: I assume he's not using any frameworks but he expects the typical behavior of a framework :)

Comment: @Matteo yes exactly, i am used to work in laravel, but it is not possible to use a framework in this case because it is a simple page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see what you're trying to do and I think you have a misunderstanding as to how functions are called. Appending the name of the function to the URL does not force php to run that function. I.e. hitting `index.php/hello` would not run `function hello() { echo "hello"; }`

**This is not how php works..**

What you must do is read the query, i.e. in PHP read what is being passed in. If your url is user.php/newUser then you must read that newUser is being passed in, and in some sort of a switch statement or otherwise (a router, a core file that calls this controller and this method, etc) tell PHP to run that method.

edit:

In the global variable `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` you will find the "route" so to speak, i.e. if you hit user.php/newUser then that global will return `/newUser`

You could do something like this, which reads the function name (and strips out the slash), then runs the function if it can find it:

```
$methodName = str_replace("/", $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
if(function_exists($methodName)) $methodName();
```

This is a very *simplified* way of doing this and widely used frameworks are obviously much more complex. This should give you an idea of how to read the URL for the route expected though and how to test if a method exists and then call a method with a dynamic name as well..

Comment: could you show me an example of that `switch/case` please? appreciate it

Comment: could you please check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412192/php-empty-result-when-calling-a-function-from-an-ajax it is the same, and you can add your answer there too with the example please

Comment: edited answer to reflect a simple way of doing what you want.. And Marco, I cannot add an answer to your question since it was flagged as duplicate to this one.

Comment: in your case using the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];` just gives me `/newUser`, how can I get the paramets? which in my case i have just one parameter which is the `name`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the lifecycle of what happens with your code:

1. JavaScript is parsed by the browser
2. JavaScript is executed
3. JavaScript loads jQuery
4. jQuery executes the code snippet you sent.
5. The code requests a resource from your webserver at "../controllers/User.php/newUser"
6. Your webserver returns a 404 because the file does not exist, as you are stating you do not use a framework.

A framework could (if you configured it to) make that route call the method on a class, but you don't have that, you just have a definition of a class in PHP. It's not initialized anywhere, and no method on any instance is ever called.

Your PHP does nothing. Your PHP is never called.

Also, your relative path is relative to the page it's executed on, not the location of the JS file.

Comment: You are explaining the problem but not really providing a solution

Comment: @Matteo You're right. Carlos Vergara suggested using Silex, which I would also suggest as a micro-framework. Honestly, my suggestion is "Use a framework", and I'm not interested in forcing my opinion on OP when I know nothing of the project's needs.

Comment: But the problem can be solved even without using a framework, and I guess the OP doesn't want to use a framework. So I think he would appreciate a simple solution

Comment: so my question is how to call that function inside that class please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Your question is that you don't know `$instance = new User(); $result = $instance->newUser(); echo $result;` ? Use a framework.

Comment: i can remove the class if you want, i just care about calling the function peae

Comment: It's not about the class itself, but the fact that you never create an instance or call the method. And that you should look into front-controller patterns and simple router-dispatcher flows.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Your class is fine, what's not fine is that there is nothing at all using it. A class is basically a printout of what an object will look like. Write something that actually queries what URL the PHP is being asked for, or use some small library like the ones I pointed you to, and have your code use that class to make some objects. Right now your code and your request are separated and disjoint, there is nothing to tie them together.

A library is always better, but you can also get away with something like `if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/newUser') !== false){/*stuff*/}`

Answer (score 2):

The class you have in there is an extant representation of what an object constructed following it will be able to do and how that will happen. It is not usable by itself.

To remedy this you need to add some PHP in another file that can call "actual" code. An actually small and clear "router" as these are called is https://github.com/sofadesign/limonade , or if you don't mind the wordiness you could use http://silex.sensiolabs.org/

Both are really simple to use, and what they do is they work as glue between the AJAX call you have in there, or any HTTP request whatsoever actually, and some runnable code, generally an anonymous function or a method, so that you do not need to build that relationship yourself but work on the actual intended behaviors of calling those URLs.

Check them out!

Comment: i just want to call that function pleas, i can't use any route or external libraries, i just need to call that fuction, could u help me please

Comment: If you can't write your own routing code, and you weren't provided with any, you're pretty much set up for failure. What do you mean call that function?

Comment: i need to call that function from the javascript ajax. it is easy help please

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not sure what you're asking for.  You need an ajax query to get data to a php method inside a class.  So you call your php file in your ajax query, that php file calls the class and runs the method on the data.

This is how ajax gets access to a class.  Make another file called user-process.php and put it in your controllers folder.

```
<?php

include 'user.php';

if($_GET['name']){  // because you're posting {name: 'John'} in your ajax
    $user = new User(); //because this is the name of your class
    $username = $_GET['name']; //I suspect you're sanitizing this input somehow before quering the database
    echo $user->newUser($username);  //this will echo asdf because the newUser() method in your User class returns asdf;
    die();

}

?>
```

PHP runs on your server.  Javascript runs on the client.  Javascript has no idea where the php files are and can't call parts of them directly because it doesn't have direct access, if it did, you wouldn't even need to make the ajax call.

To call the above script with your AJAX:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/controllers/user-process.php",
        data: { name: "John" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
```

If you wanted to include some kind of switching mechanism you could make your user-process.php file like this:

```
include 'user.php'; 

if($_GET['method']){

$user = new User(); //because this is the name of your class
$username = $_GET['name'];//I suspect you're sanitizing this input somehow before quering the    database


    switch ($_GET['method']) {
        case "newUser":
            echo $user->newUser($username);//this will echo asdf because the newUser() method in your User class returns asdf;
            break;
        case "deleteUser":
            echo $user->deleteUser($username); //you would need to make the deleteUser method in your user class
            break;
        case "etc":
            echo "etc";
            break;
    }

}
```

For the ajax call you'd need to add the method data like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/controllers/user-process.php",
        data: { method: "newUser", name: "John" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Your AJAX call should be to a URL, not a file-system location. Put in what you would type to load that page in a browser address bar. For example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://example.com/controllers/User.php?newUser",
        data: { name: "John" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
```

Everything needs to be provided in the URL that is called since the PHP does not have access to your Javascript and the Javascript does not have access to your PHP.

The PHP page then needs to return everything the Javascript needs, typically as JSON or XML. So in your `User.php` script you would update your database or do whatever you needed to have done. It would have to figure everything out from the `$_GET` array values. This could be the name of a function or just values. If results are to be returned to your Javascript they would be `echo`'ed from the script.

Maybe your `User.php` script could be:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['newUser'];
// Some code to open a database, check if the name is valid, etc., here..
echo "user name '$name'";
?>
```

Comment: Relative URIs are not the issue, and have nothing to do with the file system.

Comment: I clearly understand that Marco Dinatsoli is trying to achieve communication between his Javascript and a PHP script and he is trying to give a relative file system path. This is wrong because Javascript is running on the browser, not on the server, and does not have access to the file system. He can, by going through the proper URL get to the exact same script. So, in a way it has everything to do with the file system or at least accessing it properly.

Comment: But that's not the problem the OP is asking about. He doesn't know how to call a function inside a controller. What you're saying is right but it's another thing.

Comment: "he is trying to give a relative file system path" — No, it is a relative URL. Relative URLs are fine. (It might be a wrong relative URL, because the URL needs to be relative to the URL of the page the script is running in and not the script, but the solution is to get it right, not just replace it with an absolute one)

Comment: @Quentin, you are right that it will always be *interpreted* as a URL, so in essence it is a URL, but he has given a file system path relative to the Javascript file based on his description of the directory structure. This would only be right if his web root URL was to his **js** folder.