# php empty result when calling a function from an ajax

Tags: php

#### javascript code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../controllers/User.php/newUser",
            data: {name: "hello"}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Return value is: " + msg );
        });
```

#### User.php file

```
   <?php

    function newUser($name){
        return "hi";
    }

    function oldUser($name){
        return "ssss";
    }

    echo newUser('dd');

    echo oldUser('dd');
    ?>
```

#### The problem

I got empty results.

**however**: if i made that class just like this:

```
<?php
echo "hi";
?>
```

and called that class direclty, it works

Comment: What is telling User.php to run the newUser function, or is that your entire User.php file? My guess is you are getting an empty result because nothing is telling newUser function to run..

Comment: Could you show us the output HTML source of your script in each case?

Comment: Why have you got /newUser in your Ajax url?

Comment: @kiks73 [`PATH_INFO`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)

Comment: You know just sticking random strings (like `newUser`) in your request URL doesn't make PHP run specific functions. In your case, you'd need some PHP code to check the `PATH_INFO` environment variable and run the appropriate function if it existed.

Answer (score 1):

In user.php you have to call the function and print its output. Remember that `return` is not printing!

```
<?php

function newUser($name){
    return "hi";
}
echo newUser('lorem');
?>
```

Comment: it works when I have just one function, but i tried to add another fuction, then it returns the values of both functions

Comment: Where are those two functions? I just see one function in your code. @MarcoDinatsoli

Comment: i updated my question with the new code depending on your ansewr. the result now is `hisss`, while it should be just `hi`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli what did you expect to happen?

Comment: No it should be `hisss`because you have printed `hi` then `sss`

Comment: i need it to print just `hi`, and when i call the `oldUser`, it should print `sss`

Comment: Indeed you called the two functions! You have not call one!

Comment: how did I call the two functoins? i did this in the ajax `/newUser`.. okay what should I do to call just one function of them please

Comment: This param is meaningless for your PHP script because you have not use it. For example try to access `https://www.facebook.com/?ng=54545` and try to access `https://www.facebook.com` the same output will you have because the Facebook app does not utilize `ng` param

Comment: To solve this issue you have to do like Phil advice. Find a way to read `../controllers/User.php/THIS_PARAM` and make a conditional statement that will decide which function will be invoked!